# Mixin empty interface

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, mixins

Is there any way to mixin an empty interface to a groovy object of a wrapped primitive type? What I tried is:

```
interface B{}
a = new Boolean(false)
b = a.metaClass.mixin(B.class)
assert b instanceof B
```

The error is "groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: No default constructor for class B! Can't be mixed in."

Comment: As far as I understand it, this is not how mixins work in Groovy. Groovy mixins are used to attach static *category* methods to a class. They do not change the inheritance structure of the class at all, and they do not work on a per-instance basis. The mixin method finds all the static methods of its argument (`B.class` in this case) that have the invoking class as a first argument, and turns those methods into in instance methods of the invoking class without the first argument.

Comment: In the most recent releases of Groovy it is not necessary to use static methods in category classes if you annotate the class with `@Category`, but in any case it has to be a concrete instantiable class. Interfaces won't do. Thus the error message about lack of a default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but if you're just looking to mark particular `Boolean` instances, could you use a marker property instead of an interface? For example:

```
Boolean.metaClass.marked = false // establish the marker property

mb = new Boolean(false)
mb.marked = true

ub = new Boolean(false)

assert mb.marked
assert ub.marked == false
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.  The code you have shown there is attempting to mix an interface into a per-instance metaClass, which you can't do.  You also can't do it even if you try to mix the interface into the `Boolean.metaClass`, as opposed to the instance specific `metaClass` that you attempted to use.

Even if you could do that, the particular example doesn't make any sense as there would be no benefit so I expect that maybe you have provided an overly simplified example of what you really want to do.  Depending on what that is, maybe you can get away with generating a proxy.  You could do something like this...

```
interface B{}
a = new Boolean(false)

result = a as B

assert result instanceof B

// Boolean impements Serializable and Comparable
// so the proxy does too...
assert result instanceof Serializable
assert result instanceof Comparable

// the proxy is NOT a Boolean...
assert !(result instanceof Boolean)
```

Comment: I need a marker interface to distinguish between Boolean created by a user and my application so I was hoping to mixin an interface (mixing in an empty class works fine, but seems like interface would be conceptually a better way). From what you are saying, I understand that there is no way to make proxy that is both instance of Boolean and has a way to say that it has B as well?